# Java - Parsing Method Calls to other Class

Tags: java

I want to outsource my Menu-Creater, so i create the Class Menuhelper.

There i have a Method named "addActionListener" who adds a Action to the MenuItems

```
  public static void addActionListener(JMenuItem menuItem ) //Need parsed Method
  {

    menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        //MethodeCall
      }
    });
  }
```

How can i parse the Method who i need ? As String ?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Do you want to create a specific listener, based on the name of the menu item?

Comment: I have 10 menuitems always with the same addActionListener, but with other Method Calls (eg. ReadFile(File tfile), LoadFile(File tfile) ). So i want to reduze the Code with a extern Method "addActionListener"

Comment: @Drextor please show the code with the duplication. Your approach to use a (static!!!) method does not really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use callback method or java 8 lambda expression.

```
public static void addActionListener(JMenuItem menuItem, Callback callback) //Need parsed Method   {
   menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            callback.doAction();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: But what is the difference on the caller side? at the point where the code is used it is no (big) difference if I create an anonymous instance (or a lambda) of `Callback` or `ActionListener`...

Comment: This post has explained the differnces in both approches http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203966/anonymous-class-override-vs-passing-an-interface-for-designing-callbacks-in-jav